# VBA macro doesn't count/name files in a directory properly

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve made a simply macro to change names of files in a directory. At first it seemed correct, but then I’ve noticed something strange. For instance there is 48 files in a directory and initially the macro numbers files properly – “1”, “2”, “3” and so forth (in Immediate window the variable “i” changes from 1 to 49), but if I run the macro several times, sometimes the variable “i” changes  from 1 to 148 and a first number of files starts from 100: “100”, “101”, “102” et cetera. Then I run the macro again and it counts files properly, then – again – an error mentioned above occurs … and so on. I don’t see any rule in it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub nameChange()
Dim source As FileSystemObject
Dim fold As folder
Dim fObj As File
Dim path As String, newName As String, number As String, ext As String
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo closeSub
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .Show
  path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set source = New FileSystemObject
Set fold = source.GetFolder(path)
i = 1
newName = InputBox("New name")

For Each fObj In fold.Files
  ext = Mid(fObj.Name, (InStrRev(fObj.Name, ".")))
  Name fObj As path & "\" & newName & i & ext
  i = i + 1
Next fObj

closeSub:
 Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: For the first statement -- _the variable `i` changes from 1 to 49_ -- I interpret as `i = 1`, `i = 2`, `i = 3`, ... , `i = 48`, and `i = 49`.  However, I'm slightly confused on your description of the issue. Does it go `i = 1`, `i = 2`, ... , `i = 147`, and `i = 148`? Or `i = 100`, `i = 101`, ... , `i = 148`?

Comment: Variable „i” – in some random runs of macro - goes “i=1, i=2…i=148”, but names of files are changed in range 100-148. I have absolutely no idea how it works.

Comment: @Tom, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545234/6698332), please...

Comment: So it is API wrapper. I think that is a pretty convincing explanation of this issue. Thank you for your help.