# Rename File on Different Drive Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of file names in a worksheet. I want to read a name, find the actual file, rename it and move on to the next name.

The 1st part, retrieving the name from the worksheet and modifying it to the new name is not a problem. The problem is assigning the new name to the file.

The Name function does not work because the files are on a different drive. I also tried Scripting.FileSystemObject.

The code runs but no change is made.
Here is the code I  used...

```
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error Resume Next
Set f = fso.GetFile(fOldName)
If Not Err = 53 Then 'File not found
  'Rename file
  f.Name = fNewName
End If
```

Did I make a code mistake I'm not seeing? Should I be using/doing something else?

Finding info on VBA and/or VB6 is getting pretty rare these days.

BTW. This is for Excel 2016.

Tks

Comment: "Name can move a file across drives, but it can only rename an existing directory or folder when both newpathname and oldpathname are located on the same drive"... So why not move the file first then rename it?

Comment: File is on remote drive. I tried Name function and it caused compile error. I use FSO and it won't access remote drive. I hardcoded path to local drive file and it works. Hardcode path to remote drive file and it gives me "File Not Found" error.

Comment: is it a mapped drive, UNC path?  provide a bit more context.

Comment: These files reside on a USB HD. It is recognized as a local drive on my computer so why should I be having any problems with it. I do love this type of forum for problems. It just occurred to me that maybe there is a problem with the HD. I'll check. In the meantime, shouldn't my code be working? Obviously nothing jumped out at you so my syntax must be correct.

Comment: @Don6558, my answer below posted not as solution, but as lowlevel step by step tool, which may not work in your current environment, but it may helps to localise the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no misunderstanding...

FSO... it's bad in any case. It's just a bugsful API wrapper, written with a left chicken paw.
There are pure VB & API for more sophisticated cases.

No external libs & objects:

```
Public Sub sp_PrjFilMov()
Dim i As Byte
Dim sNam$, sExt$, sPthSrc$, sPthTgt$, sDir$

    sPthSrc = "V:\"
    sPthTgt = "R:\"

    sNam = "Empty_"
    sExt = ".dmy"   ' dummy

    For i = 1 To 5 ' create set of files for test
        Call sx_CrtFil(i, sPthSrc, sNam, sExt)
    Next

    sDir = Dir(sPthSrc & "*" & sExt, vbNormal) ' lookup for our files ..
    Do
        'Debug.Print sDir
        Select Case LenB(sDir)
            Case 0
                Exit Do         ' *** EXIT DO
            Case Else
                Call sx_MovFil(sPthSrc, sDir, sPthTgt) ' ..  & move them to another disk
                sDir = Dir
        End Select
    Loop
    Stop
End Sub

Private Sub sx_CrtFil(pNmb As Byte, pPth$, pNam$, pExt$)
Dim iFilNmb%
Dim sFilNam$
    sFilNam = pPth & pNam & CStr(pNmb) & pExt
    iFilNmb = FreeFile
    Open sFilNam For Output As #iFilNmb
    Close #iFilNmb
End Sub

Private Sub sx_MovFil(pPnmSrc$, pFnm$, pPthTgt$)
Dim sSrcPne$
    sSrcPne = pPnmSrc & pFnm
    'Debug.Print "Move " & sSrcPne & " --> " & pPthTgt
    Call FileCopy(sSrcPne, pPthTgt & pFnm)
    Call Kill(sSrcPne)
End Sub
'
```

Comment: I've just now gotten back to this project. I now realize that the problems I'm having has to do with Reference's. I've tried to add a reference to VBA and excel tells me "Name Conflict". I've searched to find what reference I should add to access FileCopy and cannot find any info. I used to program a lot in VBA and VB 6 and for the life of me I don't remember having to add a reference for file access. Believe me, I do appreciate your help but I've wasted too much time on this problem. I'll do a vb.net app instead.